# Remove duplicates excel columns

Tags: excel, duplicates

I want to remove, delete Duplicates in Excel Columns. I know how to remove duplicate rows but don't know if there is any way to do it with columns?

My Excel Sheet:

```
Name AA BB CC DD AA CC   
ID   11 22 33 44 11 33


Name AA BB CC DD  
ID   11 22 33 44
```

Comment: you could transpose the data, then remove duplicate rows, then transpose back - if not, I would say you'll end up using VBA.

Comment: @Jook is there any other ways to do it, because transpose the data would be very slow if i have tables with 1000rows and 1000columns, can you show me how to do it with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit wrong in my comment, becasue it is possible to solve this even when limited to worksheet functions.

However, here is the quick&dirty version of using `transpose`:

```
Public Sub demo()
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1000, 1000))
   .Cells = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Cells)
   .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
   .Cells = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Cells)
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You should try it, although this is more a solution for a smaller set of data. It takes a while, but it does work.